# Can I make this javascript sidebar in CSS (including the animation)?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/2/) when searching on how to make a sidebar and thought it was good, but it's in JavaScript and I don't want to use JavaScript. So am I able to do this using only CSS and HTML/5?

```
$('button').toggle(
function() {
    $('#B').animate({left: 0})
}, function() {
    $('#B').animate({left:200})
})
```

Here's a snippet of the above example:

```js
$('button').toggle(
function() {
    $('#B').animate({left: 0})
}, function() {
    $('#B').animate({left:200})
})
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#A, #B {
    position: absolute;
}
#A {
    top: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:orange;
}
#B {
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:green;
}
#BB {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"><button>toggle</button></div>
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful to you, could you select it as accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a way to make this type of navigation feasible by performing a workaround that uses the [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)  property of the checkbox input and the [General Sibling CSS Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` in order to choose the `#A` and `#B` divs and resize them to suit your needs when the checkbox is toggled.

In my example I emulated a toggle button by hiding the actual checkbox and styling the label for the checkbox (the label is also clickable and will trigger the checked attribute in the input element).

The shortcomings in this approach is that in order for the sibling selector to work, you have to actually have the toggle element in the same level as the other elements, which required some extra positioning work.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#A,
#B {
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

#A {
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: orange;
}

#B {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: green;
}

/*Hide the checkbox*/
#toggle {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  /*Set the left position to the same as the sidebar */
  left: 200px;     
  top: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 500ms;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  background: orange;
}

/* Initial sidebar state */
#toggle ~ #A {
  left: 0;
}

/*move both containers on toggle*/
#toggle:checked ~ #A,
#toggle:checked ~ #B {
  left: -200px;
}

/*move label to follow sidebar animation*/
#toggle:checked,
#toggle:checked ~ label {
  left: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="A"></div>
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">Toggle</label>
<div id="B"></div>
```

Comment: yeah, thats really nice. Thanks! One more question am I able to change the toggle to fixed instead of relative(I didn't have time to look at it properly atm)?

Comment: The positioning of the element can be any that you like or need. As long as it's clickable and the toggle element is at the same nesting level as the two divs.